# Passing data between more than one component using single model and presist it?

Tags: rxjs, angular5, behaviorsubject

I have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService<T> {
  private subject: BehaviorSubject<Partial<T>> = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<T>>(null);
  changeData(message: Partial<T>) {
    this.subject.next(message);
  }

  clearData() {
    this.subject.next(null);
  }

  getData(): Observable<Partial<T>> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I'm using it like this.
Datepicker:

```
this.ds.changeData({
  dateFrom: this.dateRange.start,
   dateTo: this.dateRange.end
});
```

Main Component:

```
 this.ds.getData().subscribe((data: FilterQuery) => {
        console.log('Update data', data);
        this.filterModel = data;
 });
```

I would like to add few more components what is the best way to presist the data and build full query object? If you have any other suggestions, I will gladly appreciate it.

Comment: What doesn't work with what you have now?

Comment: martin - it doesn't preserve the data. Cause it's always overrides the prev one.